# Who does Beatrix Kiddo thank at the end?

Tags: analysis, kill-bill

At the conclusion of *[Kill Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_Bill:_Volume_2)*, when Beatrix Kiddo has killed Bill and left with her daughter B.B., the two stay at a hotel room.

While B.B. watches cartoons on TV, Beatrix lies on the floor in the bathroom, crying and repeatedly saying "Thank you. Oh, thank you.":

[image]

Who does she thank, and what for?

Some options I've thought of, but been unable to decide conclusively:

- Bill — for saving/caring for B.B., for not attempting to kill Beatrix again despite knowing that he was on her death list (except for when she provoked him to fight on swords at the end). However, thanking him does not sit well with the fact that she did not forgive him and was still determined to kill him and got it done. Does she now regret killing him?
- Pai Mei — for teaching her, especially the Five Point Palm Exploding Heart Technique. But this feels too incidental for the scene on the screenshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

God, The Universe, Fate, etc.

She is grateful to have received the child she thought lost, she isn't thanking a person, she is just expressing gratitude.